# Accessing a named pipe endpoint in a windows service from IE using a COM enabled .NET client dll

Tags: .net, wcf, security, named-pipes

I have a WCF service hosted in a windows service. This WCF service is only going to be used on the local machine so I have chosen named pipes for endpoint. However when I try to connect to WCF service from the client instantiated by JavaScript in IE, **endpoint is not found**.

However if I stop the windows service and run the executable (it can detect whether environment is user interactive or not) then client can connect from IE as well.

BTW, I have tried setting security to None in binding configurations.

So far:

IE is running JavaScript in a lower integrity level than named pipe is created, which is normal since service has system integrity level. Question now is lowering the integrity level of created named pipe.

Answer:

I will leave this question to remind myself how stupid I am. Answer is hidden inside the question. As the executable detects that environment is user interactive, it runs all registered services in the executable. When you start a service manually, well, you start **a** service.

Answer (score 1):

When I a similar problem I fixed it by doing as Christian details in [Dealing with OS privilege 'issues' in WCF Named Pipes scenarios](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2007/12/dealing-with-os-privilege-issues-in-wcf-named-pipes-scenarios.html)

Comment: It looks like it is a different scenario, where it suggests using a windows service to host. That is what I am already doing as a must and in fact the source of the problem.
Thanks for the link anyway.